# How to split dates into groups of 24 hours -BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

this is my goal, split the dates into groups of 24 hours, but those depends of the data, not of a very specific date

Let's say these are the calls from a call center, I want to know how many sessions I had, but those sessions are valid for 24 hours, those 24 hours are starting to count since the first date_sent, if the next call is later of those first 24 hours, a new session would be created

The expected results are like this:
First 3 columns are those I already have in the table, fourth one is the required calculation

```
identifier  customer_id date_sent               StartOfSession          sessionId
456456150   5366    2020-09-01T10:17:48.360000  2020-09-01T10:17:48.360000  1
456456150   5366    2020-09-01T18:24:45.552000  2020-09-01T10:17:48.360000  1
456456150   5366    2020-09-02T10:20:46.283000  2020-09-02T10:20:46.283000  2
456456150   5366    2020-09-02T18:25:01.911000  2020-09-02T10:20:46.283000  2
456456150   5366    2020-09-03T10:20:38.407000  2020-09-02T10:20:46.283000  2
456456150   5366    2020-09-03T18:23:35.915000  2020-09-03T18:23:35.915000  3
456456150   5366    2020-09-04T10:19:46.474000  2020-09-03T18:23:35.915000  3
456456150   5366    2020-09-04T14:22:17.236000  2020-09-03T18:23:35.915000  3
456456150   5366    2020-09-04T18:24:33.155000  2020-09-04T18:24:33.155000  4
456456150   5366    2020-09-05T10:19:48.871000  2020-09-04T18:24:33.155000  4
456456150   5366    2020-09-05T18:25:07.968000  2020-09-05T18:25:07.968000  5
456456150   5366    2020-09-06T10:19:34.808000  2020-09-05T18:25:07.968000  5
456456150   5366    2020-09-06T18:26:17.705000  2020-09-06T18:26:17.705000  6
456456150   5366    2020-09-07T10:21:28.585000  2020-09-06T18:26:17.705000  6
456456150   5366    2020-09-07T18:24:17.123000  2020-09-06T18:26:17.705000  6
456456150   5366    2020-09-08T10:20:09.850000  2020-09-08T10:20:09.850000  7
456456150   5366    2020-09-08T18:24:32.733000  2020-09-08T10:20:09.850000  7
456456150   5366    2020-09-09T10:20:05.336000  2020-09-08T10:20:09.850000  7
456456150   5366    2020-09-09T12:12:41.137000  2020-09-09T12:12:41.137000  8
456456150   5366    2020-09-09T18:24:25.783000  2020-09-09T12:12:41.137000  8
```

I've tried using window functions, but I cannot achieve the same expected results:

```
  SELECT identifier, customer_id, date_sent,
    FIRST_VALUE(date_sent) OVER (PARTITION BY A.identifier, A.customer_id, CAST(A.date_sent AS DATE) ORDER BY UNIX_SECONDS(TIMESTAMP(date_sent)) RANGE BETWEEN 86400 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) FirstV_date1
  FROM `sandbox.testing` A
  WHERE identifier = '456456150'
AND date_sent between '2020-09-01' AND '2020-09-10'
```

Those would be my actual results

```
identifier  customer_id date                    FirstV_date1
456456150   5366    2020-09-01T10:17:48.360000  2020-09-01T10:17:48.360000
456456150   5366    2020-09-01T18:24:45.552000  2020-09-01T10:17:48.360000
456456150   5366    2020-09-02T10:20:46.283000  2020-09-02T10:20:46.283000
456456150   5366    2020-09-02T18:25:01.911000  2020-09-02T10:20:46.283000
456456150   5366    2020-09-03T10:20:38.407000  2020-09-03T10:20:38.407000
456456150   5366    2020-09-03T18:23:35.915000  2020-09-03T10:20:38.407000
456456150   5366    2020-09-04T10:19:46.474000  2020-09-04T10:19:46.474000
456456150   5366    2020-09-04T14:22:17.236000  2020-09-04T10:19:46.474000
456456150   5366    2020-09-04T18:24:33.155000  2020-09-04T10:19:46.474000
456456150   5366    2020-09-05T10:19:48.871000  2020-09-05T10:19:48.871000
456456150   5366    2020-09-05T18:25:07.968000  2020-09-05T10:19:48.871000
456456150   5366    2020-09-06T10:19:34.808000  2020-09-06T10:19:34.808000
456456150   5366    2020-09-06T18:26:17.705000  2020-09-06T10:19:34.808000
456456150   5366    2020-09-07T10:21:28.585000  2020-09-07T10:21:28.585000
456456150   5366    2020-09-07T18:24:17.123000  2020-09-07T10:21:28.585000
456456150   5366    2020-09-08T10:20:09.850000  2020-09-08T10:20:09.850000
456456150   5366    2020-09-08T18:24:32.733000  2020-09-08T10:20:09.850000
456456150   5366    2020-09-09T10:20:05.336000  2020-09-09T10:20:05.336000
456456150   5366    2020-09-09T12:12:41.137000  2020-09-09T10:20:05.336000
456456150   5366    2020-09-09T18:24:25.783000  2020-09-09T10:20:05.336000
```

I've also tried using self join, but I rather not because that's very expensive, but, any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how many rows in your table?

Comment: Try `BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING`

Comment: The table would have like  100 millions of rows, that's why I rather not use self join

Also, I used 86400 preceding because date was converted to UNIX time and 86400 = 24 hours

Comment: Sorry missed that. Can you explain to me in plain english what the logic behind the expected results is?

Comment: Let's say these are the calls from a call center, I want to know how many sessions I had, but those sessions are valid for 24 hours, those 24 hours are starting to count since the first date_sent, if the next call is later of those first 24 hours, a new session would be created
I edited the post, I expect to be clearer

Comment: let me ask you differently - how many max rows in this table per identifier/customer_id? run `SELECT COUNT(1) cnt FROM \`sandbox.testing\` GROUP BY identifier, customer_id ORDER BY cnt DESC LIMIT 1` for this!

Comment: 1460 should be the rows
I made a new approach making adding the date inside the partition, but I'm sure that is not the way to solve it, anyway, is closer to the total of sessions expected, but no lucky :(

Comment: obviously it is not a way! it was not what I had in mind asking for that number - so you are saying that max per partition is about 2K - right? confirm please as in this case solution is relatively simple and I can jump in and answer when time allows

Comment: Yeah, that's the volume per partition, kind 2K
I mean that I edited the post with that new approach
I'll appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (assumes that date_sent column is of timestamp data type - as it looks like in provided example)

```
#standardSQL
create temp function get_sessions(x array<timestamp>)
returns array<struct<date_sent timestamp, sessionStart timestamp, session string>>
language js as """
  output = []; session = 1; sessionStart = x[0]; total_dur = 0;  
  a = {}; a.date_sent = x[0]; a.session = session; a.sessionStart = sessionStart;
  output.push(a);
  for(i = 1; i < x.length; i++){
    a = {};
    total_dur += x[i].getTime() - x[i-1].getTime();
    if(total_dur>24*3600*1000){
      total_dur = 0; session++; sessionStart = x[i];  
    };
    a.date_sent = x[i-1]; a.sessionStart = sessionStart; a.session = session;
    output.push(a);
  }
  return output;
""";
select identifier, customer_id, date_sent, sessionStart, session
from (
  select identifier, customer_id, get_sessions(array_agg(date_sent order by date_sent)) sessions
  from `project.dataset.table`
  group by identifier, customer_id
), unnest(sessions)
```

if to apply to sample data in the question - output is

[image]

Important: assumption here - based on your comments - volume of rows per partition (identifier, customer_id) is relatively small (~2K) so js udf memory limit is not a problem here)

Comment: I know it says that "avoid thanks", but it helped me a lot, I wanted to point that. thanks!